# Update a clock using ActionListener - Java

Tags: java, timer, jframe, actionlistener

I want a digital clock in Java displaying time and date, and the colons should blink. However, I can't make the colons blink. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class DigitalClock {

  public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    ClockLabel dateLable = new ClockLabel("date");
    ClockLabel timeLable = new ClockLabel("time");
    ClockLabel dayLable = new ClockLabel("day");

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Digital Clock");
    f.setSize(300,150);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    f.add(dateLable);
    f.add(timeLable);
    f.add(dayLable);

    f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ClockLabel extends JLabel implements ActionListener {
  String type;
  SimpleDateFormat sdf;
  public ClockLabel(String type) {
    this.type = type;
    setForeground(Color.green);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    switch (type) {
      case "date" : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("  MMMM dd yyyy");
                    setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    break;
      case "time" : if(seconds % 2 != 0) sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
                    else sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss a");
                    setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    break;
      case "day"  : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE  ");
                    setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
                    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    break;
      default     : sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
                    break;
    }
    Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
    t.start();
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      Date d = new Date();
    setText(sdf.format(d));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have the following lines:

```
case "time" : if(seconds % 2 != 0) sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
              else sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss a");
```

That way, the colons are visible when the seconds are odd, else the colons are not visible.

The problem is that if I launch the program and the second is odd at that time, then the colons are always visible. I don't understand why, since the second changes (time updates), but the colons don't.

Comment: You are only setting the SimpleDateFormat once at start up in the constructor of ClockLabel. You should switch formats in actionPerformed()

Comment: By the way, these date-time classes are now legacy. Checkout java.time classes, the ThreeTen-Backport project, and the ThreeTenABP project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to put this check

```
if(seconds % 2 != 0) 
  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
else 
  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh mm ss a");
```

inside the `actionPerformed` method. thats the way you can switch the : on each sec.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your project in debug mode you will understand that the switch-case statement runs only once (on startup). This is normal according to the above implementation as the logic is placed inside the constructor which is called only tree times.

In short, you need to change this implementation radically.